# Jquery Mobile Ajax and Sound

Tags: iphone, html, jquery-mobile, html5-audio

when I am moving from the page where we have HTML5 streaming audio, the sound is stopped.

http://silver.georates.net/silver/broadcast.html#podcast

How to make it possible, so that when I am navigating between pages, the sound will stay in Iphones safari?